# When using SSH to install the library, Python 2.7 reported an error, but the Python in the virtual environment is 3.10

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, pip

input：`pip install loguru`

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement loguru (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for loguru
```

but，
when I input: `python -V`
shows：`Python 3.10.6`

I have rebuilt the virtual environment and reinstalled vscode.

Comment: Always use `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: How is ssh relevant here? If you're using ssh to invoke python or pip remotely, please [edit] your question to show the exact ssh command that you're running.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue and just need to use pip3 during installation. Using only pip seems to default to Python 2.7 in the environment